# Finding $\int \frac{dx}{(a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{(a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x)^2}$, where $a,b$ are constants.

I tried it some specific values of $a,b$ and tried many substitutions but it doesn't seem to work.

Just throw me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Vidyanshu Mishra I received an invitation from you to join you in a chat;  However, I cannot access that chat. So, I'll have to say "no thank you" for now

Comment: @amwhy actually I had something to discuss. But now I am a bit busy, let's leave it for sometime. At least till the end of my mid term exams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$\dfrac1{(a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x)^2}=\dfrac{\sec^4x}{\left(a^2+b^2\tan^2x\right)^2}$$

Write $b\tan x=a\tan y$